# This page is taking too long to load

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a view page on php zend framework. View page has  10 methods. Each method has 3 sql queries returning thee values. I am calling these 10 methods 10 times. All queries is working on the table of 24,000 rows. It's taking 2-3 minutes to load the view page. I am storing the function results in arrays and using the array values to display.

How can I implement output caching on this?

Source code for my view part is:
Those are my variables:

```
$no_of_customers = array();
$no_of_customers_EE = array();
$no_of_customers_NEE = array();
$unique_customers = array();
$unique_customers_EE = array();
$unique_customers_NEE = array();
$no_of_sent = array();
$no_of_sent_EE = array();
$no_of_sent_NEE = array();
$no_of_opened = array();
$no_of_opened_EE = array();
$no_of_opened_NEE = array();
$no_of_surveys = array();
$no_of_surveys_EE = array();
$no_of_surveys_NEE = array();   
$promoter = array();
$promoter_EE = array();
$promoter_NEE = array();
$detractor = array();
$detractor_EE = array();
$detractor_NEE = array();
$passive = array();
$passive_EE = array();
$passive_NEE = array();
```

one of the function i am using is

```
function unique_customer($con,$start_date,$end_date ,&$unique_customers,$i,$customerTable,&$unique_customers_EE,&$unique_customers_NEE)
{

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emailAddress) AS Total, product FROM $customerTable  WHERE importDate >='$start_date' AND importDate <'$end_date' ;");
$rs = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$unique_customers[$i] = $rs['Total'];
unset($rs);

$result_EE = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emailAddress) AS Total_EE, product FROM $customerTable  WHERE importDate >='$start_date' AND importDate <'$end_date' AND product = '';");
$rs_EE = mysqli_fetch_array($result_EE);

$unique_customers_EE[$i] = $rs_EE['Total_EE'];
unset($rs_EE);

$result_NEE = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT emailAddress) AS Total_NEE, product FROM $customerTable  WHERE importDate >='$start_date' AND importDate <'$end_date' AND product != '';");
$rs_NEE = mysqli_fetch_array($result_NEE);

$unique_customers_NEE[$i] = $rs_NEE['Total_NEE'];
unset($rs_NEE);

}
```

Calling these functions 10 times and storing the values in arrays

Comment: How do you expect people to help you when you can't format your question?

Comment: apply limit to your query. The limit number can be the expected maximum number of result per page `LIMIT 30`. It will reduce the delay on MySQL.

Comment: Do you have relevant indexes on the MySQL table(s)?

Comment: Caching is usually done on the web server, not in code.

Comment: First thing you should do is to profile your queries to check how you can speed them up, and find out which one is causing problems.